# How to place parameter so that rails request can find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-get

I have the following piece of ruby code:

```
authenticate_this(request.env["SOME_ID"])
```

What I want to know is how do I place this "SOME_ID" within the HTTP GET request. 
From what I understand, these rails request parameters are preset? If so what is the "SOME_ID"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails request parameters are available in the `params` hash. Put this next line in your ERB

```
= debug params
```

This line will tell you all about the params hash. Key values include

```
params[:id]
params[:object_id] # In a route like users/1/listings/1, this would be params[:user_id]
params[:form_contents] # the contents of a form are available in params
```